# Is it acceptable to use the noun "swing" for both a short round trip and an extensive circular tour in AmE?

Tags: meaning, american-english, word-usage

I remember once coming across, while browsing some bilingual dictionary, the noun "swing" pointed up as an AmE equivalent for "circuit".

But, sadly enough, what the bilingual dictionary didn't say was if this usage had any currency at all in modern day AE -- and if it was to some extent more common than the term "circuit", as well as appropriate to use for both a short round trip and an extensive circular tour.

In addition, how does a *swing* differ from a *circuit* and from a *round trip*?

You might want to consider the following sources for this.

> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swing (head to Definition 6b by the bottom of the page)
>
> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Swing?s=t (head to BOP also)
>
> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circuit
>
> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/circuit?s=t

The prince and princess, winding up a seven-day swing throughout the US...
[source](https://www.mdc.edu/main/images/Prince%20Felipe%20of%20Spain%20opens%20Miami%20Book%20Fair%20International%20-%2011_17_2013%20_%20MiamiHerald_tcm6-85009.pdf)

Comment: It tends to mean a short trip.  Seven-day swing is a perfect example.  No one would say 6-month swing.  Then you'd start speaking of a tour or even a stint (extended period of time spent somewhere).  Don't ask me what the cutoff is, though.  Swing implies a speedy trip without much substance.

Comment: the usage sounds odd to me, but maybe persons older than me or from a different part of the country may use it that way. the usage of `swing` that i am accustomed to is the phrasal senses `swing over` or `swing by` meaning "to make a brief or spontaneous social call"

Comment: @DavidM how about for scenic circular trips or tours shorter than a a day and than an hour?

Comment: @jlovegren Swing by definitely.  Swing over, not as much to my ear.  7-day swing is something used nearly exclusively in tabloid headlines.  Royals on 7-day swing through Canada, etc.  I'm from the Northeastern United States, and I'm 38, for reference.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet The problem is this ... It's not a commonly used phrase by "real people".  You see this mostly in newspapers, etc.  So, yes you could use it for any short trip.  But, would you?  Eh . . . not really.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Later this evening I will write a formal answer for you, if you still wish.

Comment: @DavidM Sure, David. Anytime you want. No need to make things snappy. ;-)

Comment: @DavidM  By the way, is "swing" generally used by travel and hospitality business professionals to designate a circuit or a round trip, or is it chiefly a journalese term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To formally answer your question:

A swing (noun) is generally a short trip, never a long circuitous trip somewhere.   And, the terminology is usually used in newspaper headlines.  And, as such, it tends to be very informal.

> Royals to make 7-day swing through Canada.

The body of the article would probably not use the term swing anywhere in it.  Rather, they'd refer to it as a 7-day visit, trip, tour, etc.  Swing would likely only be used in the headlines.

(This is a common theme with newspapers, who use punchier, informal, shorter terms in their headlines than they'd ever permit in their articles.)

On rare occasion, I've seen this used in advertisements for things like short cruises:

> Take a 3-hour swing around New York Harbor.

This, just like the journalistic usage is an informal term for a short trip.

Compare this to the usage as a verb:

> *Swing by my place* after work, and I'll give you the $5 I owe you.

It means, come over to my home, and it implies that you are going to stop by, but not stay for long.

I hope this answers your question.